# Synchronize the width and position of the sub menu with a page container

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, megamenu

I am using Max Mega Menu plugin for my menu. Menu bar in my theme is not 100% width of the page, there is some space left for the logo.

So when I set 100% width of the dropdown panel, it's the same width like the menu itself, not 100% of the page. When I set 1170px as the width of the dropdown panel, it's top-left corner is where the menu item is, so half of it or more is outside of screen. And it depends on which menu item I open - the dropdown panel has position:absolute to the menu item which is relative.

I want it to be the same width as the page and independent from specific menu item.

I've tried:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

or

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

but it does not work.

In the plugin documentation they are saying:

> Enter a jQuery selector to synchronize the width and position of the sub menu with existing page element (e.g. body, #container, .page).

but I don't know how.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle.net showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What class or ID do you have on the page container?

If you HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class='content'>My page content..</div>
```

.. then use '.content' as the Panel Width.

If you page looks something like this:

```
<div id='page'>My page content..</div>
```

... then use '#page' as the Panel Width.

Comment: Width of the panel isn't the problem, the problem is it's placement. I need the panel to be visible on the website, but if it's the 100% width of the page, it starts where the menu item is and ends way outside of the page itself, so the whole panel isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a jQuery selector for the mega panel width option in the mega panel theme page, the mega panel will expand to the width of that element. So on a site where I was using the Headway theme, I used #whitewrap in that field. That caused my mega panel to expand the full width of #whitewrap, which is the full width of the page in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To make the mega menu drop downs span the entire width of the page (rather than just the width of the menu), go to Mega Menu > Menu Themes and set the following values:

Panel Width (Outer): body

Panel Width (Inner): .container